# Babel: transpile into single output file

Tags: babeljs

Babel 7.2.0

I need to transpile my JS-files and combine they into single result file. This is my attempt:

`npx babel --source-root src/index.js --out-file lib/result.js --minified --presets @babel/preset-env`

But I get the error:

> babel:
>   stdin compilation requires either -f/--filename [filename] or
>   --no-babelrc

I tried `-f` and `--no-babelrc` but it doesn't help me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current command never tells Babel what file to compile, so it is expecting the file content to come from stdin. Since stdin also has additional requirements, you get that error. The real issue though is, you don't actually seem to want to use stdin. If we look at your command

```
babel --source-root src/index.js --out-file lib/result.js
```

the core issue is that `--source-root` takes a value, so you've essentially done

```
babel.transformFile({
  filename: ????
  sourceRoot: "src/index.js"
});
```

because nothing in your command actually gives the filename. Presumably you intend `src/index.js` to be the filename, so you may just be misusing `sourceRoot`? My guess would be that you want

```
npx babel src/index.js --out-file lib/result.js --minified --presets @babel/preset-env
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I get a single result file but it hasn't the content of my all JS-files. It has only content from `src/index.js` file. Therefore when I run `node lib/result.js` it doesn't work.

Comment: @AndreyBushman That's correct. If you want to bundle your files up, you'd want to use Webpack. The CLI's `--out-file` more is for if you already had a single file as input.