# Babel produces empty JS file from TS

Tags: typescript, babeljs

I'm trying to build a single-file library based on TS sources using pure Babel (without Webpack&co)

All sources (including subfolders) are located in src folder, in .babelrc I used transform:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-typescript"]
}
```

for build I have used

```
babel src --out-file dist/libraryName.js
```

and after execution the file is empty (console has no errors). Did I miss something?

Comment: What happens if you specify your entry file instead of `src`?

Comment: it produces file which contains import/export only.

Comment: And can those exports be used to import your library?

Comment: I think you should take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53791435/babel-transpile-into-single-output-file).

Comment: No it can't be used, because it trying to import nonexistent file:

Answer (score 1):

I've used Babel 7.12.9, and... it doesn't read it's own .babelrc! So, when I renamed .babelrc into babel.config.json - problem is gone. Hope, it helps someone else.